# how to make display responsive in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

i am beginner in flutter , i was creating a widget that represents schedules in a football league , but after i executed i found that my screen is not responsive and the display is not fine , a yellow zone appeared , and the display of the date and time is not always in the center, the widget became not ergonomic
here an image after execution:
[image]

Here the code i have tried :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


class BroadcastSchedule extends StatelessWidget  {

  String home;
  String homeImage;
  String away;
  String awayImage;
  String time;
  String date;

  BroadcastSchedule(this.home,this.homeImage,this.away,this.awayImage,this.time,this.date);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return  Card(
      elevation: 4.0,
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
      ),
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        child:
        Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            CircleAvatar(
              backgroundImage: NetworkImage(this.homeImage),
            ),
            const SizedBox(width:10.0),
            Spacer(),
            Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
              children: <Widget> [
                Text(this.home),
                const SizedBox(height: 5.0, ),
              ],
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(top:20.0, left: 20.0, right: 20.0),
             child: Container(
               padding: EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
               decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.grey[700],
                 borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(11.0),
               ),
               child: Column(

                 children: [
                   Text(this.time,style: TextStyle(
                       fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                       fontSize: 18.0,
                       color: Colors.white,
                   ),),
                   const SizedBox(height: 5.0, ),
                   Text(this.date,style: TextStyle(
                       fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                       fontSize: 16.0,
                       color: Colors.white
                   ),),
                 ],
               ),
             ),
           ),
           
            Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget> [
                Text(this.away),
                const SizedBox(height: 5.0, ),
              ],
            ),
            Spacer(),
            CircleAvatar(
              backgroundImage: NetworkImage(this.awayImage),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

My girl is to learn how to make my code responsive and that will not at any case have an error in display like this

after adding Expanded above column , the grey Box is still misplaced and there is a problem with the long Text

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like your text is overflowing.

Added Expanded above Column widget.
Expanded :A widget that expands a child of a [Row], [Column], or [Flex]
so that the child fills the available space.

[image: sol]

But now we have to Fix Long text.

```
Expanded(child:  Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget> [
                Text(this.away),
                const SizedBox(height: 5.0, ),
              ],
            ),
            Spacer(),
            CircleAvatar(
              backgroundImage: NetworkImage(this.awayImage),
            ),)
```

Comment: is there any other solution?

Comment: and where to add Expanded exactly?

Comment: it did not solve the problem of the long text and the grey box , i ll update my final result